# sending data with post request in angular and handling that data in node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I was trying a post request in angular and i had to send some data with it but i am unable to handle that data at the back-end Nodejs or may i am not sending the data right way.
I need help!

```
$scope.sendData = function() {
  $scope.obj = {
    username: $scope.username,
    password: $scope.password
  };

  console.log($scope.obj);

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/upload",
    data: $scope.obj,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  })
};

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("hello");
});
```

when i console log `req.body` i get the data but in very weird format:

[image: this is the output i get]

help please

Comment: Do you really need the `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? NodeJS, by default, allows you to receive JSON. Try to remove that header, and it should work fine.

Comment: if i remove this line from my request..i am getting an empty object as output

Comment: Can you try to set the header value as `application/json`?

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: Change the value of the header from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json` and retry.

Comment: by doing this i get an empty object in the console

Comment: Make sure you're using [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). Without it, `req.body` won't work, AFAIK.

Comment: i am using body parser in node

Comment: Be sure to include `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: still an empty object

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify $scope.obj before sending to the server.

`$scope.obj = JSON.stringify($scope.obj);`

Add this line just below your `console.log` statement.